# HAproxy - How to comunicate to private network from a public ip

Tags: nginx, haproxy

I have a private ip on my network that it is a ipmi server.
  I have installed another server(Centos 7) and assign a public ip to use as a proxy for to be able to reach from an exernal network the ipmi server.
  I'm tried to do this with nginx and also with haproxy but there is something wrong on the configuration. Anyone can help me?

```
Here is my nginx config:

#cat /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf 
upstream ipmi_backend {
    # the ipmi server
    server 10.150.0.34:443;
    keepalive 64;
}
server {
    listen 8070;
    server_name ipmi.server.it;
    location / {

#        add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options "";
        proxy_set_header X-Content-Type-Options "";
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass https://ipmi_backend/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
        proxy_set_header Connection "keep-alive";
        proxy_store off;
    proxy_set_header Host "ipmi.server.it:443";

}

========================================================================

Here my haproxy.cfg:

#cat haproxy.cfg
global
    log         127.0.0.1 local2
    pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid
    maxconn     4000
    #stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock user haproxy group haproxy mode 660 level admin
    # turn on stats unix socket
    stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats

defaults
    mode                    http
    log             global
    option          http_proxy
    timeout connect         50s
    timeout client          50s
    timeout server          50s

frontend  http-in
    bind localhost:8071
    mode http
    default_backend servers

backend servers
    server server1  10.150.0.34:443 check
```

With nginx the error i can reach the login page, but after the credencial the page says:
  Your session has timed out. You will need to open a new session.
  With haproxy the error message is:
  This site can’t provide a secure connection.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you figured this out yet? I am having the same issue :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SuperMicro's IPMI, the "Your session has timed out" error is likely due to SSL redirection. You can change it within Configuration > Port:

[image: Screenshot of Supermicro IPMI' Port Page]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it applies for your case as well, but for me it helped to unset the `Authorization` HTTP header on the reverse proxy. Any frontend authentication *must not* be passed to the SuperMicro IPMI, otherwise it seems to confuse the IPMI firmware.